# ds3.js Horizontal bar - How to centralise y axis?

Tags: d3.js

I'm following [Mike Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837) to produce a horizontal bar chart with positive and negative values.

I'm trying to centralise the y-axis, so that there is always the same length of x-axis each side. But can't find any examples out there.  I want the scale of the x-axis to remain sensitive to the data, so I don't want to specify the range.

I can't get the example he gives to work. :

> For the quantitative scale, compute the data domain (the minimum and maximum value) using d3.extent:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }))
     .range([0, width]);
```

> Nicing the scale will extend the extent slightly to the nearest round numbers. If you want the zero-value to
>   be centered in the middle of the canvas, take the greater of the
>   minimum and maximum value by magnitude, or simply hard-code the
>   desired domain.

Any examples of how to correctly calculate the domain or help most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's discover which one is greater, the minimum or the maximum value:

```
var greater;

if (Math.abs(d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.value})) > Math.abs(d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value}))) {
  greater = Math.abs(d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.value}));
  } else {
  greater = Math.abs(d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value}));
  };
```

And then set the scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([greater * -1, greater])
 .range([0, width]);
```